# Send check box status (checked or not) through Hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

***.cshtml page**

```
@{
        var companyLoginFormViewModel = TempData["CompanyLoginFormViewModel"] as CompanyLoginFormViewModel;
    }     

    <form class="login-form" action="@Url.Action("Login")" name="companyLoginForm" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="@companyLoginFormViewModel.LoginViewModel.RememberMe" />

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase">@L("LogIn")</button>

    </form>
```

**Note :** This value (`@companyLoginFormViewModel.LoginViewModel.RememberMe`) is always `true` or `false`

**VMs**

```
public class CompanyLoginFormViewModel
{
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class LoginViewModel
{
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

**Action Method :**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<JsonResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel)
{

  if (!ModelState.IsValid) //here it shows validation error
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException(L("FormIsNotValidMessage"));
    }

}
```

**Question :** When I pass a `true` or `false` through hiden field,it always says `The RememberMe field is required.` validation error on the server side.But that property is `not a required` field ? Could you tell me why this is happening ? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using the strongly typed helpers to generate you view. And why are you using `ViewData` instead of passing the model to the view (and using `@model CompanyLoginFormViewModel`? Type of `bool` is a required field - it must be either `true` or `false` and can never be `null`. The only explanation is the value is not either true of false. Inspect the html your generating (although this will all be solved out of the box by generating you view correctly anyway)

Comment: And to test - just comment out the hidden input

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yep,it generates like this `<input type="hidden" name="rememberMe">`.Is that mean value is `null` ? But the model's above property is `false` no.So how can it be happened ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it means it's `null` - it would have `value="True"` or `value="False"` otherwise. And please stop generating your html manually :) - your using MVC - make use of its features.

Comment: You have not shown your GET method where you initializing your instances of the models and setting their properties so impossible to help other than to repeat - use the html helpers - `@model CompanyLoginFormViewModel` and `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoginViewModel.RememberMe)` - half the code and you will never get an error

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes,when I use like above then no errors.But here I'm not using model binding.It is being used `TempData`.So how can I set the proper value for the hidden filed ? Thanks.

Comment: OMG I hadn't even noticed that (assumed it was `ViewData`). `TempData` is for passing data between controller methods (e.g. from a POST method to a GET method when redirecting - and its `TEMP`orary - it only lasts one request and its gone). You can't use it like that in the view. Just pass your model to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes,I have used that the same way you have mentioned above.B'cos above page doesn't have any input controls.I have taken those values from the previous request (i.e. prev form) and put those values into `TemData` and used like above.All the other hidden properties are working fine.Only issue is this `check box`.Any feedback ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why your persisting with this awful code. Add `<div><span>Remember me: </span><span>@companyLoginFormViewModel.LoginViewModel.RememberMe</span></div>` in your view and check the output. If it does not output `"True"` or `"False"` it means that the value is `null` (which means you have to debug your code to find out why)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes,this is the out put of it.`<div><span>Remember me: </span><span>False</span></div>`.It nicely shows as `False` but why it doesn't work with the manual hidden field which I showed above ? Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is there any issue the way I have set the values for the manual hidden field ? Thanks.

Comment: No idea - something else in your code is causing it [ now that sounds familiar :) ] - but I need some sleep now. Hopefully you will sort it out (suggest you start by hard-coding it using `value="False"` and check that it does submit correctly).

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK sure.I'll try to sort out it and let you know.Thanks for the support and Good Night ! :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have found out the issue due to your continuous support.The issue was we have to use `ToString()` with the boolean properties.This works : `<input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value=@companyLoginFormViewModel.LoginViewModel.RememberMe.ToString() />`.If you can put your suggestions and etc.. later then I can close this thread.Thanks a lot gain for the Great support :)

Comment: You should add your own answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `class="ignore"` in you hidden field, and put this in your javascript code to ignore in client side:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

server side:

```
@Html.Hiddenfor(model => model.rememberMe, 
                new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", false }})
```

you are using MVC ,Please use the facilities it:

```
@model CompanyLoginFormViewModel
@{

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Your Action","your controller",FormMethod.Post))
{

   @Html.Hiddenfor(model => model.rememberMe,
                new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", false } })

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase">@L("LogIn")</button>

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. It only applies to client side validation and OP is not even using any client side validation (and hidden fields are ignored by default so even if OP was, this would be unnecessary.